# what tools do you use for writing jquery code and debugging your code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what tools do you use for writing jquery code and testing/debugging your code?

Comment: Since jQuery is a JavaScript library,I think you can use Firebug for Mozilla extension

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for firefox is essential - it lets you:

- Debug your code (step into, out, etc)
- Set watch variables and expressions
- See contents of all requests and responses, as well as all content received
- Time to download each resource
- Inspect and modify the DOM, including viewing the DOM after it has been dynamically modified by JavaScript
- And much more!

There are also debuggers available for Internet Explorer and other browsers, but none are quite as powerful as firebug.

Depending on the language, there are other resources available for debugging server side code that come in quite handy, too. But that is another question...

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is very handy for quick snippet debugging.  There are competitors such as [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/), but fiddle remains my favorite, even though it's only in alpha at the moment.

Of course I think Chrome's developer tools and FireBug/Web Developer for Firefox are tremendously helpful as well...each tool has it's area that it helps with.

Lastly, let's not forget: [the jQuery API itself](http://api.jquery.com/), a **tremendous** resource for information.

Comment: +1 for jsfiddle. Nothing like being able to prototype within seconds. Only if it had grouping, I would have used it as an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome Developer Tools are really powerful.

Also great for debugging CSS and HTML issues. The DOM highlighting is really handy.

Answer (score 1):

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) might be what you are looking for. It has support for jQuery, debugging and also CSS, html and ruby, and is generally very nice to work with.

Answer (score 1):

even if it is funny, I find IE 8 dev tools very convinient for js debug

Answer (score 0):

`console.log();` is your friend. Pick up its output with Firebug for Firefox, or the built-in consoles in the developer tools in Safari and Chrome (IE no help as usual).